# How can access a object property value from Objects contains array of objects in Js

Tags: javascript

i  got ane object contains array of objects.

```
Object {
  "isLoadingAPI": true,
  "orgAPIData": Array [
    Object {
      "color1": "#009fe8",
      "color2": "#9c3ab4",
      "color3": "#0bb694",
      "face": true,
      "fingerprint": "true",
      "id": 1234,
      "messageLimit": 10,
      "name": " הטסטים משרד",
      "visible": true,
    },
    Object {
      "color1": "#009fe8",
      "color2": "#9c3ab4",
      "color3": "#0bb694",
      "face": true,
      "fingerprint": "true",
      "id": 3245,
      "messageLimit": 15,
      "name": "טסט",
      "visible": false,
    },
    Object {
      "color1": "#009fe8",
      "color2": "#9c3ab4",
      "color3": "#0bb694",
      "face": false,
      "fingerprint": "false",
      "id": 333,
      "messageLimit": 10,
      "name": " התחבורה משרד ",
      "visible": true,
    },
    Object {
      "color1": "#009fe8",
      "color2": "#9c3ab4",
      "color3": "#0bb694",
      "face": true,
      "fingerprint": "false",
      "id": 9112,
      "messageLimit": 10,
      "name": "פלאריום",
      "visible": true,
    },
    Object {
      "color1": "#009fe8",
      "color2": "#9c3ab4",
      "color3": "#0bb694",
      "face": false,
      "fingerprint": "true",
      "id": 1008,
      "messageLimit": 10,
      "name": "ספיאנס",
      "visible": true,
    },
  ],
}
```

So here i want to access all  **"messageLimit"** value from above list.

i want to store values in a global variable.

lets say if i am going to console that variable i should get only the values (10,15,10...) like this.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Look into [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?retiredLocale=nl).

Comment: You need to add what code you tried before you can 'want' anything :)

Comment: @ChinmayeeSahoo, the link I provided is the answer to *How can I achieve this*. If you need additional help, you could ask nicely, not demand it.

Comment: ok..its my bad...can you please write code for that with the output?@EmielZuurbier

Comment: It seems that others have already posted the correct answer. Also check out the link provided by @pilchard which has answers that also apply to your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this by Arrays map method.

The arrays map method takes a function as parameter and what ever this function returns will be returned in your results.

So it can be like this.

```
  var messageLimits = object.orgAPIData.map(oapi=>oapi.messageLimit)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use map function:

```
const messageLimits = object.orgAPIData.map(apiData => apiData.messageLimit);
```